# Bulk move SVN branches

Tags: svn, version-control, branch, directory

I'm trying to find a way to bulk move 100's of SVN folders created under the traditional branches folder to an archive folder sitting directly under the branches folder.

- trunk/
- tags/
- branches/

  - archive
  - branch1
  - branch2
  - branch3
  - branch4
  - branch5
  - branch6
  - etc

I don't want to have to move these all one at a time are there are just too many and most of the pointers I've found on this deal with moving individual files within a folder not the actual top level folders themselves.

Anyone any idea's on how to move these in bulk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: You don't have to *archive* the branches. Just delete them. Subversion still keeps the branches, and they can be *undeleted* or the history retreived if needed. I know a lot of CMs end up doing this anyway because developers get nervous about it.

To answer your question, you can use *sparse checkouts* to checkout the branch folders and not there content.

```
 $ svn co --depth=immediates http:/svn.vegicorp.net/repo/branches
```

This will checkout all 100 or so branches, but not anything under the branches themselves. You'll have just 100 or so empty folders. The checkout takes only a minute or two, and since these are nothing but empty directories, not much room on your hard drive.

Now, you can use whatever mechanism you like to *move* the branches to that archive folder. For example, let's say you have a list of branches you want to move in `branch_list.txt`:

```
$ svn mkdir archive
$ while read branch_to_move
> do
>     svn mv $branch_to_move archive
> done < branch_list.txt
```

Commit your changes, and that's it. You've moved the branches to the `archive` folder.

Comment: Only got a chance to look back at this this morning. Thanks, this worked perfectly.  Always feel a little uncomfortable deleting things which is why I wanted to keep them in an archive folder even though as you explained it is still possible to retrieve these branches.